# Unable to install MySQL 5.7.12 in RedHat in a separate directory

Tags: mysql, installation

I am trying to install the MySQL version 5.7.12 into RedHat in a non default data path.

The installation syntax used

```
/app/mysql/5.7/bin/mysqld --initialize --user=mysql --basedir=/app/mysql/5.7 --datapath=/app/mysql/data
```

`/app/mysql/data` is a softlink to `/data`

I got the following error.

```
2016-05-19T02:57:28.087915Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicitdefaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-05-19T02:57:28.090891Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
2016-05-19T02:57:28.090910Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: *`the data directory has files in it. Aborting.`* - is there anything inside `/data`?

Comment: No. That's why it's a strange message. 
`ls -l /data`
total 0

Comment: Does MySQL have permissions to access the new datadir? Apparmor/selinux running and maybe blocking access?

Answer (score 1):

`bin/mysqld --initialize --user=mysql --datadir=/app/mysql/data --basedir=/app/mysql/5.7`

I specified `--user` parameter and the error no longer appearing.

```
2016-05-19T10:27:17.440353Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-05-19T10:27:17.661087Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
2016-05-19T10:27:17.713953Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2016-05-19T10:27:17.777797Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxx.
2016-05-19T10:27:17.780306Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2016-05-19T10:27:17.781230Z 1 [Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: xxxxxxx
```

Comment: and also change command string, was data path, now --datadir :)

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure MySQL user has permission to access these files . Moreover I see you are using datapath.tthis is wrong. Please use argument datadir . And then give a try.